# The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors

I'm getting the error "The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'" in the code below:

```
import 'dart:async';

abstract class SettingsBase {
  Future<String> getSetting<String>(String key);
  Future saveSetting<String>(String key, String value);
}

class InMemorySetting extends SettingsBase {
  final settings = <String, String>{};

  @override
  Future<String> getSetting<String>(String key) {
    if (settings.containsKey(key)) {
      return Future.value(settings[key] as String);
    }

    if (key == "theme") {
      return Future.value("light" as String);
    }

    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Future saveSetting<String>(String key, String value) {
    settings.putIfAbsent(key, () => value);
    return Future.value(true);
  }
}
```

What have I missed?

[image]

Comment: Almost true. It turned out to be an extra generic argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a generic type of String which overwrites Dart's String type.

Just remove the extra String in

```
getSetting<String>
```

Answer (score 2):

Do some reading about what a [generic](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics) is.

I'm not sure why, but you're adding a generic to your function prototype in your abstract class with the name of `String`. So the types of the `key` and `value` parameters are of the generic type, just with a placeholder name of `String`.

Remove those generics:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

abstract class SettingsBase {
  Future<String> getSetting(String key);
  Future saveSetting(String key, String value);
}

class InMemorySetting extends SettingsBase {
  final settings = <String, String>{};

  @override
  Future<String> getSetting(String key) {
    if (settings.containsKey(key)) {
      return Future.value(settings[key] as String);
    }

    if (key == "theme") {
      return Future.value("light" as String);
    }

    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Future saveSetting(String key, String value) {
    settings.putIfAbsent(key, () => value);
    return Future.value(true);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I added an extra generic type argument named `String` to the method. The code below works.

```
import 'dart:async';

abstract class SettingsBase {
  Future<String> getSetting<String>(String key);
  Future saveSetting(String key, String value);
}

class InMemorySetting extends SettingsBase {
  final settings = <String, String>{};

  @override
  Future<String> getSetting<String>(String key) {
    if (settings.containsKey(key)) {
      return Future.value(settings[key] as String);
    }

    if (key == "theme") {
      return Future.value("light" as String);
    }

    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

  @override
  Future saveSetting(String key, String value) {
    settings.putIfAbsent(key, () => value);
    return Future.value(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow community is so fast, I opened a reply form, went for my tea, submit my reply, and there are already replies :)